# Can I use 1N4148 diodes instead of a 1N4001 diode for reducing the speed of a 5V 1.8W fan?

Tags: current, diodes, series, fan

Looking at this [1N4148 datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81857/1n4148.pdf), it seems that the forward continuous current is 0.3A, thus 300 mA. So if I add two in series, I will get 600 mA.

I want to use diodes to reduce a 5V 1.8W fan speed. The current through the fan is P = V * I <=> I = P / V = 1.8 / 5 = 360 mA.

Can I use two 1N4148 diodes in series, resulting in a voltage of 5 - 0.7 * 2 = 3.6 V (having thus about 72% fan speed), because 360 mA < 600 mA?

(note: I know a 1N4001 is better, having a 1A limit, but I don't have them yet).

Or did I make a mistake in my calculation or is there another effect why two 1N4148's cannot be used?

Comment: The diodes are in series so have the same current through them, it's not split in two. Draw the circuit and see where the current loop is... Also, your fan may be 1.8 W at 5 V, but may well be different at 3V6. Better to use PWM anyway.

Comment: @awjlogan ok, clear (I want to connect it to a 5V source, I will than use another diode, hopefully I have some which are more suitable). I don't like PWM (no microcontroller involved).

Comment: How do you feel about a 555?

Comment: Nah, use a 741 to drive the fan

Comment: I have some 555's left, not 741's

Comment: Fans use  pretty efficient SMPS to commutate the phase current so their average rate VI load characteristics look like a variable resistor down towards stall speed only when SPINNING. So choose  your % RPM above start Voltage or to decide on then choose V drop with power diodes... and by every means possible leave an optimal gap from fixed grill or heatfins to moving blade to reduce noise and then seal the gaps so air  does not leak to keep it  quieter from Eddy  Current winds. Or the if want a thermistor to FET controlled fan speed, make one. With some BJT in between for gain and offset bias.

Comment: You can gang a bunch of 1N4148’s together in xSyP arrays or get the right part or use BJT super  bias

Comment: The diode would survive a short term test, the 300 mA limit is based on the rise in junction temperature. At a 300 mA forward current the forward voltage of the diode is 1.2 VDC or more

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Thanks for the comment, it seems it is more complicated than I thought, I will check all terms you mentioned to see the relation between them :-)

Comment: It's simple for DC muffin Fans because above stall speeds they are almost linear loads for "RPM/volt" . For quiet, compare fan in your hand vs next to a grill ( hear that?) next inside a "plenum", to avoid turbulence, then make as short as possible. still quiet ? and better inertial air flow.  Any 1N400x will do, get a bunch, cheap

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 300 mA rating is in the Absolute Maximum Ratings table - you don't normally want to go near those ratings.

The 1N4148 is intended as a small signal diode.  If you look at the Electrical Characteristics table, you will see that most specifications are given with a 10 mA test current, so you should only use a 1N4148 with currents in that range.

As others have said, for diodes are in series, EACH diode carries the full current.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the problem with designing using the 'Absolute Maximum Ratings' table.  An important detail novice's frequently misunderstand.

Comment: Yes indeed, I also was not so aware of this. For the time being, I think I will find another diode (or just use full power if that's it), and in future project I know what to use better, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Components in series have the same current through them — it doesn't divide. All of the current goes through all of the devices.

If one diode has a limit of 300 mA, then two of them in series still have a limit of 300 mA.

Comment: Ok clear, than I need to check if I can user a better suitable diode.

Answer (score 2):

If you place two components in series, current flowing through first diode and second diode is equal. It means that through both of your diodes will flow 0.6 A (actually 0.5 A -> you have to use new 3.6 V if you want to compute current to fan) -> they are going to be burned. You should choose other diode with bigger forward current.

Also, when you want to compute current to fan, you should use 3.6 V instead of 5 V, because of voltage drops across these diodes.

Comment: Btw, I could use maybe 3 or 4 diodes until I get under 300 mA right?

Comment: Actually, if you look on that formula I = P/U, with lower voltage u get higher current. I would prefer using some kind of PWM modulation - 555 as seen above

Comment: Yes indeed, I only could use resistors, but they need to be of high power.

Comment: Power loss is unavoidable in linea mode and 50% at V/2. In fact 40 yrs ago the Japanese would expect  a hot R and Thermistor to be cooled by fan to detect Fan Fail and cut off fan power